# C# , How to output specific array searches?

Tags: c#

The program I am creating prompts the user to enter an amount of months, the amount of work absences he/she has had in each month, and the amount of absences allowed per month. It is supposed to calculate the average amount of work absences by an employee as well as the amount of times that he/she went over the max absences allowed.

I was able to calculate the average with an array loop but was having issues with the times he/she has gone over the max absences. I am using the binary search method but have trouble outputting the specific amount of months that the employee has gone over the allowed absence amount.

This is my current code for that section:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbOfAbsences.Length; i++)
{
    sum += numbOfAbsences[i];
    averageAbsences = (sum / numbOfMonths);
    Console.WriteLine("Employee was absent " + averageAbsences + " times per month.");
}

a = Array.BinarySearch(numbOfAbsences, maxAbsences);
if (a >= maxAbsences)
{                
}
```

I am unsure of what would go under the last set of brackets, as I am not trying to point out whether the max amount was exceeded but rather the amount of times that it was.

Thank you for the help in advanced.

Comment: is your averaging program correct? you divide `sum` before it's complete calculating

Answer (score 0):

First off, the question is not clearly stated. It boils down to this:

"What's a good way to take an int array of sums and divide them all by a count to produce a double array of averages? Also, how can I count the values of an int array greater than a threshold? (Here's what I've got so far: )"

Second, the code snippet is very confusing. More precisely... It's not indented correctly. Not all of the variables used are defined, so we have to guess what they are. The variable names aren't very descriptive, so one has to look at how each variable is used to understand it. Most importantly however, this is no encapsulation. No objects, no functions... just raw code that you need to read every line of very carefully to understand.

Contrast the snippet with this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ArraySearch_StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] employeeAbsencesEachMonth = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            int maxAbsencesAllowedPerMonth = 3;

            double averageAbsencesPerMonth = GetAverageAbsencesPerMonth(employeeAbsencesEachMonth);
            Console.WriteLine($"Employee's Average Absences Per Month: {averageAbsencesPerMonth}"); /* 3 */
            int numTimesMaxAbsencesExceeded = GetNumMaxAbsencesViolations(employeeAbsencesEachMonth, maxAbsencesAllowedPerMonth);
            Console.WriteLine($"Number of Times Employee Exceeded Max Absence Limit: {numTimesMaxAbsencesExceeded}"); /* 3 */

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static double GetAverageAbsencesPerMonth(int[] employeeAbsencesEachMonth)
        {
            // ???
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private static int GetNumMaxAbsencesViolations(int[] employeeAbsencesEachMonth, int maxAbsencesAllowedPerMonth)
        {
            // ???
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

This snippet is extremely clear. Even without a description, it's immediately apparent what's being asked, and how to tell if an answer is correct. Because the questions have been translated into a function signature and the context has been translated into a driver in which the functions are called, complete with setup and an expected result.

Handily, this implies a simple format for the answer, creating a good chance you can copy-paste it directly into your code:

```
private static double GetAverageAbsencesPerMonth(int[] employeeAbsencesEachMonth)
{
    return employeeAbsencesEachMonth.Sum() / employeeAbsencesEachMonth.Length;
}

private static int GetNumMaxAbsencesViolations(int[] employeeAbsencesEachMonth, int maxAbsencesAllowedPerMonth)
{
    return employeeAbsencesEachMonth.Count(x => x > maxAbsencesAllowedPerMonth);
}
```